# Can't get test coverage with jest + puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I have project [Excellent.js](https://github.com/vitaly-t/excellent) setup for automatic testing with [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) and [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), which successfully runs all the tests, which [can be seen on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/vitaly-t/excellent/builds).

But after a lot of configuration tweaks I have been unable to make it report correct coverage. No matter what tests are executed, the coverage does not reflect it at all.

The library contains only a single JavaScript file `excellent.js`, and my [jest.config.js](https://github.com/vitaly-t/excellent/blob/master/jest.config.js) was set up as instructed for coverage:

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverage: true,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/excellent.js'
    ],
    testURL: 'http://localhost/',
    setupFiles: [
        './src/excellent.js'
    ]
};
```

Here're [all the tests](https://github.com/vitaly-t/excellent/tree/master/test), which all pass if you do first `npm install`, and then `npm test`.

So what am I missing? Why can't I get the coverage reported correctly?

Comment: great library name, btw 

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Thank you! :) I may need till Monday, to be able to test and evaluate your answer. Much appreciate it!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ISSUE**

Most of the tests are using Puppeteer and when the code is executed in the browser provided by Puppeteer, that code execution is not reflected in the Jest code coverage reports.

**SOLUTION**

None of the tests require Puppeteer so I refactored them as Jest tests.  The code coverage is now accurate and is currently the following:

`excellent.js |    63.47 |     48.7 |    57.78 |    62.96`

I created a [pull request with these changes](https://github.com/vitaly-t/excellent/pull/8).

**Additional Info**

It is now possible to [generate code coverage reports for Puppeteer pages](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-coverage) and there is a library to help [view them in Instanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/puppeteer-to-istanbul) but those code coverage reports are generated independently from Jest.

To do testing in Puppeteer pages and have the coverage from those tests reflected in the reports generated by Jest would require merging the Puppeteer page coverage reports with the Jest coverage report.

Comment: This is a great effort, thank you! Integrating together all these test packages is such a daunting task. And it doesn't get any easier. I'm glad I can at least stick to just one of them - `jest`.

Comment: your welcome, glad it was helpful!  yeah, the tests really cleaned up nicely, it always feels great to delete a bunch of code and dependencies  good luck with the project!

Comment: @BrianAdams Why https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer#__docusaurus explain: _Generating code coverage for test files using Puppeteer is currently not possible if your test uses page.$eval, page.$$eval or page.evaluate as the passed function is executed outside of Jest's scope._

Comment: @BrianAdams Is it possible to replicate drag and drop functionality with Jest?