# How to test custom web component with jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, puppeteer, web-component

I would like to test some custom web components and use jest.js as test runner (due to its support for ES6).

Chromium supports commands like

```
window.customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElementClass);
```

to register a custom web component.

However, `window.customElements` does not seem to be known in the context of jest tests.

As a work around I tried to use **jest in combination with puppeteer and express** to run the `customElements` part in Chromium.

However, I have difficulties to inject the custom element class `TreezElement` in the evaluated code:

treezElement.js:

```
class TreezElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback () {
      this.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
    }
}
```

treezElement.test.js:

```
import TreezElement from '../../src/components/treezElement.js';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import express from 'express';

describe('Construction', ()=>{

    let port = 3000;

    let browser;
    let page;
    let element;
    const width = 800;
    const height = 800;

    beforeAll(async () => {

        const app = await express()                   
                    .use((req, res) => {                       
                        res.send(
                        `<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>            
                            <body>
                            <div id="root"></div>                           
                            </body>
                        </html>`
                        )
                    })
                    .listen(port);

        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
          slowMo: 80,
          args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
        });

        var pages = await browser.pages();
        page = pages[0]; 

        await page.setViewport({ width, height });        

        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000'); 

        element = await page.evaluate(({TreezElement}) => {
            console.log('TreezElement:')
            console.log(TreezElement);
            window.customElements.define('treez-element', TreezElement);
            var element = document.create('treez-element');
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            return element;           
         }, {TreezElement}); 

    });


    it('TreezElement', ()=>{   

    });    

    afterAll(() => {
        browser.close();
    });        

});
```

Maybe `TreezElement` is not serializable and therefore `undefined` is passed to the function.

If I try to import the custom element class `TreezElement` directly from within the evaluated code ...

```
element = await page.evaluate(() => {
            import TreezElement from '../../src/components/treezElement.js';
            console.log('TreezElement:')
            console.log(TreezElement);
            window.customElements.define('treez-element', TreezElement);
            var element = document.create('treez-element');
            document.body.appendChild(element);
            return element;           
         });
```

... I get the error

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

**=> What is the recommended way to test custom web components with jest?**

Some related stuff:

- [Web Component / HtmlElement : unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463201/web-component-htmlelement-unit-testing)
- https://itnext.io/testing-your-javascript-in-a-browser-with-jest-puppeteer-express-and-webpack-c998a37ef887
- [How to mock dependencies for ES6 unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379078/how-to-mock-dependencies-for-es6-unit-tests)
- [Can't get test coverage with jest + puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625029/cant-get-test-coverage-with-jest-puppeteer)
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer

Comment: I created a feature request for direct support of web components: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8818

Comment: Here is a related pull request for jsdom: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2548

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSDOM 16.2](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/16.2.0) includes basic support for custom elements and is available in [Jest 26.5](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v26.5.0) and above. Here's a simple Jest test that shows it working:

```js
customElements.define('test-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const p = document.createElement('p')
        p.textContent = 'It works!'
        this.appendChild(p)
    }
})

test('custom elements in JSDOM', () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>Custom element test</h1> <test-component></test-component>`
    expect(document.body.innerHTML).toContain('It works!')
})
```

Output:

```
$ jest

PASS  ./test.js
✓ custom elements in JSDOM (11 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.409 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Note not all features are supported yet, notably **shadow DOM does not work**.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a DOM that supports server side rendering of web components. It also supports testing web components with Jest.

**DOM:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/happy-dom

**Jest environment:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-happy-dom

**To install it**

npm install jest-environment-happy-dom --save-dev

**To use it:**

Edit your package.json to include the Jest environment:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --env=jest-environment-happy-dom"
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The name of package has been changed to "@happy-dom/jest-environent"

Answer (score 2):

use electron runner can include all node and chrome env,
use this to replace jsdom

https://github.com/facebook-atom/jest-electron-runner

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly version that kind of works. Some further notes on this:

- express.js is configured to work as **file server**. Otherwise there would be issues with mime type or cross origin checking for the imported ES6 modules.
- The class `TreezElement` is not directly imported but using the work around of creating an **extra script tag**
- There are issues with instance methods regarding the **code coverage**. It does not seem to be possible to directly call the constructor of `TreezElement` (inherits from HTMLElement, => `illegal constructor`). An **instance of the element class** can only be created with `document.createElement(...)` in puppeteer. Therefore, all the instance methods cannot be tested in Jest but only static methods. The instance methods and properties can be tested in puppeteer. However, [the code coverage of jest does not consider the code coverage of puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625029/cant-get-test-coverage-with-jest-puppeteer).
- The created element of type `TreezElement` can be returned in form of an [ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). **Accessing the properties and methods of the element** instance is quite cumbersome (see example below). As an alternative to the handle approach, the `page.$eval` method can be applied:

  ```
  var id = await page.$eval('#custom-element', element=> element.id);
  ```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>    
    <body>  
        <div id="root"></div>   
    </body> 
</html>
```

treezElement.test.js

```
import TreezElement from '../../src/components/treezElement.js';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import express from 'express';

describe('Construction', ()=>{

    let port = 4444;
    const index = Math.max(process.argv.indexOf('--port'), process.argv.indexOf('-p'))
    if (index !== -1) {
        port = +process.argv[index + 1] || port;
    }

    var elementHandle;      

    beforeAll(async () => {

        const fileServer = await express()  
                    .use(express.static('.'))                          
                    .listen(port); 

        var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
          slowMo: 80,
          userDataDir: '.chrome',
          args: ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs']         
        });

        var pages = await browser.pages();        
        var page = pages[0];
        await page.goto('http://localhost:'+port + '/test/index.html');        

        await page.evaluate(() => { 
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type='module';
            script.innerHTML="import TreezElement from '../src/components/treezElement.js';\n" +
                            "window.customElements.define('treez-element', TreezElement);\n" +
                            "var element = document.createElement('treez-element');\n" +   
                            "element.id='custom-element';\n" +         
                            "document.body.appendChild(element);"; 
            document.head.appendChild(script);            
        });     

        elementHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => { 
           return document.getElementById('custom-element');
        });       

    });      

    it('id',  async ()=>{   
       var idHandle =  await elementHandle.getProperty('id');
       var id = await idHandle.jsonValue();
       expect(id).toBe('custom-element');
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        browser.close();
    });    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (limited) approach is to use `Object.create` as a work around to create an instance of the custom web component, without using `window.customElements.define` and `document.createElement(..)` :

```
import TreezElement from '../../src/components/treezElement.js';
var customElement = Object.create(TreezElement.prototype);
```

This way the **instance methods can be tested directly** in jest and the tests are included in the code coverage, too. (Also coverage issues of my other answer regarding puppeteer.)

A major disadvantage is that **only the methods can be accessed**, not the properties. If I try to use customElement.customProperty I get : `TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

This is caused by the check `!module.exports.is(this)` in Element.js:

```
Element.prototype.getAttribute = function getAttribute(qualifiedName) {
  if (!this || !module.exports.is(this)) {
    throw new TypeError("Illegal invocation");
  }
...
Element.prototype.setAttribute = function setAttribute(qualifiedName,value){
if (!this || !module.exports.is(this)) {
   throw new TypeError("Illegal invocation");
}
```

Another disadvantage of `Object.create` is that the constructor code is not called and not included in the test coverage.

If the command `window.customElements.define(..)` is directly included in a class file that we would like to import (e.g. treezElement.js) ... the `customElements` property needs to be mocked before including the import:

customElementsMock.js:

```
export default class CustomElementsMock{} //dummy export

//following command mocks the customElements feature to be able
//to import custom elements in jest tests
window.customElements = {
    define: (elementName, elementClass)=>{
        console.log('Mocked customElements.define(..) for custom element "' + elementName + '"');
    }
};
```

usage in treezElement.test.js:

```
import CustomElementsMock from '../customElementsMock.js';
import TreezElement from '../../src/components/treezElement.js';
var customElement = Object.create(TreezElement.prototype);
//...
```

(I also tried to put the mock code directly at the beginning of `treezElement.test.js` but [all the imports are executed prior to the script doing the import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551366/what-is-the-defined-execution-order-of-es6-imports). That is why I had to put the mocking code in an extra file.)